# Cannot Read image of undefined in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm use the filter method to pick-out one featured item in an array and use that to render it's state in my Home Component. I'm using the filter method in the MainComponent, passing that to the Home Component, where I want the AddCard functional component to render. I'm getting the error message of "cannot read image of undefined" so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong in passing my props.

MainComponent.js

```
class Main extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            whyfastpack: WHYFASTPACK
        };
    }

    render(){

        const LandingPage =()=>{
            return (
                <Landing />
            );
        };

        const HomePage=()=>{
            return (
                <Home   
                    lightweight={this.state.whyfastpack.filter(lightweight => lightweight.featured)[0]}
                />
            );
        };

        return(
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage} />
                    <Route path ='/home' component={HomePage} />
```

HomeComponent.js

```
   ...
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md m-1'>
                                <AddCard />
                            </div>
                        </div>


   ....

function RenderCard({ item }) {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardImg src={this.image} alt={item.name} />
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
                <CardText>{item.comment}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );
}


function AddCard(props) {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md m-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.lightweight} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

whyFastPack.js

```
export const WHYFASTPACK = [
    {
        id: 0,
        image: 'images/pnw.jpg',
        name: 'Reduce Weight',
        comment: 'Carry only what you need for the day, not a month! With fast-packing you only need to bring enough to get you through each day!',
        featured: true,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neglected to pass a `lightweight` prop to `AddCard` from `HomeComponent`.

```
<div className='col-md m-1'>
  <AddCard lightweight={this.props.lightweight} />
</div>
```